# R : Getting p-value for a mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, p-value

I am trying for the first time to do a mixed effects logistic regression with R and I have some difficulties. Using 120 samples, I want to see if the group of age and the sex of the patient have an impact on the protein (=1 if protein level>threshold value) and I consider the run as a random effect.

```
library(lme4)
log.lm = lme4::glmer(protein~sexe.f+groupe.f+sexe.f*groupe.f+(1|run_fusion_R1R3), data=data, family=binomial(link="logit"))
anova(log.lm, test="Chisq")
```

But the function anova() does not give any p-value :

```
Analysis of Variance Table
                Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
sexe.f           1  0.3934  0.3934  0.3934
groupe.f         1 15.6975 15.6975 15.6975
sexe.f:groupe.f  1  5.5219  5.5219  5.5219
```

Why doesn't "anova()" return p-value ? Is there any problem with my model ? Should I use an other function ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because you don't have any DF. You were running a full interaction model.

Comment: This link will come in handy as you navigate your way through the computation of p-values in mixed effects models: https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/MM/MM_TestEffects.html.